# What happens to Infiltrating Cylons on New Caprica when Galactica jumps away?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

If a Cylon leader is infiltrating and still on New Caprica when Galactica jumps away, do they count as a "human character left on New Caprica", thus triggering their execution? This could be relevant for the agenda cards: Join the Colonials and Show Their True Nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pegasus rulebook, pg 7:

> A Cylon Leader is considered a “human
>   player” when he is Infiltrating and a
>   “Cylon player” when he is not
>   Infiltrating.

I don't see an exception for infiltrating cylons on pg 17:

> Once the Admiral has ordered Galactica
>   to leave and ended the game, destroy
>   all civilian ships still on New
>   Caprica, and execute any human players
>   still on a New Caprica location. If
>   after resolving those losses, no
>   resource has been reduced to 0 or
>   lower, the humans win the game!

Therefore, infiltrating cylons are humans and would be executed.

Comment: I agree. This is also supported by the Unofficial FAQ: http://tinyurl.com/32j7e2m